# how to reload the grid store after calling iframe in extjs4?

Tags: php, extjs, extjs4

I have a grid panel which keep some variables. When I use this item(update-node765), `PHP` side works. After it works I can edit my selected data in database but I cannot reload the store.
I tried aftershow, beforshow function by calling this method  `fileStore_yon.reload();` but I cannot do it. I know `fileStore_yon.reload();` it works normally.
Also, I tried some codes in `PHP` side;

```
   <script>fileGrid_yon.store.reload(); </script>
```

Finally

```
fileStore_yon.loadById(sadas);
```

How can I solve this problem? thanks..

```
        {
        id: 'update-nod765',
        text: 'İçeriği Düzenle',
        iconCls:'icon-grid-ren',
        listeners : {
            click : function(){
                var rec = fileGrid_yon.getSelectionModel().getSelected();
                if(rec){
                    var icerik_id=rec.data.id;
                    var kategori_id=rec.data.kategori_id; 
                    new Ext.Window({
                        iconCls: 'icon-plus',
                        title: 'İçerik Düzenleme Ekranı',
                        closeAction: 'close',
                        width:820,
                        autoScroll:true,
                        modal:true,
                        height:530,
                        listeners:{
                            beforeshow : function(bu){
                                fileStore_yon.reload();
                            },
                              afterShow : function(bu){
                                fileStore_yon.reload();
                            }

                        },
                        html:'<iframe src="phps/icerikDuzenle.php?gelen_id='+icerik_id+'&kategori_id='+kategori_id+'" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"><p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe>'
                    }).show();
                }else{
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Uyarı Geçersiz İşlem','Öncelikle listeden bir içerik seçmelisiniz.');
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Go through your questions http://stackoverflow.com/users/1702486/user1702486?tab=questions and mark best answers accepted or provide your own answers and mark them as accepted. The reason is to show that you care.

Comment: I mark all of the correct answers thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using store.load() ?  I am unfamiliar with reload() method.